# UITableView with fixed 5 rows

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an app where I need to show 5 rows of data all the time. The data for the rows comes from a `NSArray` of strings. The `NSArray` can be empty or can contain a max of 5 elements. I wanted to force the `UITableView` to have 5 rows displayed all the time. I tried it and when the `NSArray` has just 1 element, iOS throws a exception due to the fact I have defined 5 rows (`numberOfRowsInSection`). How do I make the `UITableView` to display 5 rows (Grouped, single line) all the time without raising a exception?.
Also, how do I center the section header? I'm using `titleForHeaderInSection` method.

Comment: Do you take the content for the cells with a call like [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ?
Is it possible to post some code snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to implement logic that's based on the size of your `NSArray` of strings.

Find the total number of strings using `[NSArray count]` . Then, check if `indexPath.row` is less than `[NSArray count]` and use your standard implementation where you get the string from the array using `indexPath.row` as your index. If `indexPath.row` is not less than `[NSArray count]`, then you can just keep the cell empty (and not try to retrieve anything from your array). Then you won't have that exception.

For the title header, does this work?
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2539133?start=0&tstart=0

Replace `UITextAlignmentCenter` with `NSTextAlignmentCenter`.

It works around your issue by using `viewForHeaderInSection` and returning a centered `UILabel`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could fill out the NSArray with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. To display 5 rows your should to return constant 5 in the numberOfRowsInSection and in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` generate your empty cell `if indexPath.row >= [array count]`.
2. To display header in the center use

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```